# React native generating apk problem ':app:minifyProductionReleaseWithR8'

Tags: react-native, build.gradle, apk

I can successfully build and run my project on both android and ios. I can manage and publish versions on app store but i can not generate apk on android studio which gives me an error

`> Task :app:minifyProductionReleaseWithR8 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:minifyProductionReleaseWithR8'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.R8Task$R8Runnable`

I deleted node modules and installed again
I cleared gradle and kotlin cache
I re-installed android studio , tried to sync gradle with project , clean project and clean yarn cache

[image: My gradle version is here , another co-worker can build and generate apk's successfuly with this versions][image: output of my error is here]

> Task :app:minifyProductionReleaseWithR8 FAILED

Comment: Anyone can help maybe ?